# Display PNG only files in directory PHP

Tags: php

I am having trouble sorting the PNG files in my script.

```
<?php
if ($handle = opendir('../banners/')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="../banners/<?php echo $entry; ?>" target="_blank"><img src="../banners/<?php echo $entry; ?>" /></a></td>
                    <td><?php echo $entry; ?></td>
                    <td><a href="<?php echo $adminurl; ?>banners/delete/<?php echo $entry; ?>/"><img src="<?php echo $siteurl; ?>style/images/delete.png" class="delete-icon" alt="Verwijder" /></a></td>
                </tr>
        <?php }
    }

    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```

This works fine but it also displays the index.php, PSD files, basically every file.

How can I make it so it only displays .png extension files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) function:

```
$dir= "../banners/";
$pngimages = glob($dir."*.png");
```

Comment: Thought that I had my script working by the use of your code but it doesn't really display any files now, how can I implement your code?